# There is this driver "who would go" or "who goes"

Tags: grammar, tenses

If you want to explain a situation where, for example, you want to talk about a bus driver who goes and take a coffee sometimes on the way, which one would be more appropriate:

> There is this one driver, who goes and gets a coffee on the way and you have to wait like for 10 minutes.
>
> There is this one driver, who would go and get a coffee on the way, and you would have to wait like for 10 minutes.

Comment: Both sound fine. Very slight difference in meaning but inconsequential in this informal kind of speech.

Comment: Sorry, OT...  One day the army unit stations a philosophy student as sentry. If he hears a sound, he is supposed to call out: "Who goes there?"  But this guy, when he *thinks* he heard a sound, but isn't sure, calls out: "Who would go there?"

Comment: I don't see how this is OT. The question is asking about the usage of "who would go" versus "who goes." The OP gives also the context for which he is asked, which means it's not a too generic question. It could be the answer doesn't change basing on the context, but that doesn't make the question OT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me the "would" form is appropriate either if the whole thing is hypothetical:

> There might be one driver who would go and get a coffee...

or in the past:

> There used to be one driver who would go and get a coffee ...

If it is non-hypothetical and present, I wouldn't use "would":

> There is this one driver, who goes and gets a coffee ...

Comment: Can we use "There is this one driver" at the beginning in a hypothetical situation?

Comment: No, because you are *asserting* ("there __is__ this one driver"), so there is nothing hypothetical about it.

Comment: But we can say: "there would be this one driver", right? I am just looking for alternatives instead of might.

Comment: No. The only sense I can make of that ("would" with the main verb) is past habitual (like "used to be"). To get a hypothetical you need to use either a verb like "might" or "could be", or a condition "if there were".

Comment: Can we say if I am making an assumption(explaining a situation). "It's just like you don't study that much, but you would study sometimes."

Comment: That example makes no more sense than the earlier ones. If you want to use "would" you need to be talking about either habit in the past, or about a hypothetical situation: but for the latter you need something (usually an explicit conditional, but in can probably be contextual) to establish the hypothetical context. I don't understand why you keep asking variations on the question "Can I use 'would' in this way you've told me I can't".

Comment: Because I need a punch in the face before I get it. Anyway, was confused. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

When we are telling a story, we usually use either the present tense or the past tense. ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_mode#Narrative_tense)) Your first sentence uses the present tense, which is fine:

> There is *[present existence]* this one driver, who goes and gets *[present habit]* a coffee on the way and you have *[present habit]* to wait like for 10 minutes.

Your second sentence mixes the present tense and past tense, which is **not** fine:

> There is *[**present** existence]* this one driver, who would *[**past** habit]* go and get a coffee on the way, and you would *[**past** habit]* have to wait like for 10 minutes.

So just change *is* to *was*:

> There was *[past existence]* this one driver, who would *[past habit]* go and get a coffee on the way, and you would *[past habit]* have to wait like for 10 minutes.

(You also omitted the *to* from *have to* in your second sentence.  I assume that's just a slip.)