# who would vs who will

Tags: grammar

> Woman: Who would need to have a robot follow you around? I can certainly carry my own basket.
>
> Man: Robovie is not for you. It is developed to provide living support for the elderly. Perhaps you will want one when you are 60!

Comment: This looks like editing to me.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: More context is needed before this can be answerable. But then it would still lack research, and probably be unsuitable here for [other reasons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/would-vs-will).

Answer (score 1):

The use of ***would*** in your sentence is related to how we build conditional sentences (we can add a few words to make it a conditional sentence of the second type (unreal present): *Who would need to have a robot follow you around even if it were more affordable?* So, *would* shows that what we are discussing is actually unreal, **hypothetical**.

***Will*** in *Perhaps you will want one when you are 60* is used to make a **prediction** about the future.